# C++20 in g++10: generator not defined

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

This MCVE works fine in Visual Studio.

```
#include <experimental/generator>
#include <iostream>

std::experimental::generator<int> f() { for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) co_yield i; }

int main ()
{
    for (int i : f())
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

but in g++10, which is listed as having full support or C++20's coroutines, it does not.

(Taking out `experimental` doesn't help.)

I am compiling thus: `g++ -g -std=c++2a -fcoroutines -c main.cpp`.

It complains that there is no include file generator, and if I take out the `#include`, that generator is not a part of std:: or is not defined. I suppose there's another name for it in the new standard? Or if not, what do I do instead to get a coroutine that uses `co_yield`?

Comment: The `experimental` part in `<experimental/generator>` and `std::experimental::generator` means that it's not part of the standard. As such not all compilers might implement it in their standard libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing in [GCC's status list](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) alongside its coroutine support says it supports anything other than [p0912r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0912r5.html), which does not provide `std::generator`, experimentally or otherwise.

I recall that [VS added `<experimental/generator>` a few years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6qq5t1/why_isnt_there_a_stdgenerator_in_the_coroutines_ts/); I guess GCC never did.

If it's currently proposed for inclusion in C++, and you can find the relevant proposal, perhaps you can track its support status. But honestly, for now, you'd be better off writing your own that works until it becomes part of some actual standard.

**tl;dr: Though it *is* a coroutine, this feature is not *part of* the Coroutines TS.**

Comment: "*this feature is not part of the Coroutines TS.*" Or C++20.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution -- I knew C++20 doesn't include something with that name -- but I suppose I phrased the question wrong. I'll accept and ask another question.

Comment: @TopologicalSort I mean, the answer is still that GCC doesn't — and shouldn't necessarily be expected to — have it.

Comment: This feature is now a part of C++23

Answer (score 0):

If you need a generator for g++11 and above, copy paste the one here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle