# C++20 coroutines: need a function that uses co_yield

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

This MCVE won't compile in g++10 (with `-std=c++21 -fcoroutines` options).

```
#include <iostream>

int f() { for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) co_yield i; }

int main ()
{
    for (int i : f())
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

What should that top line of `f` look like, so I get a working coroutine? Or does something else need to be done to make a working coroutine? It needs to be part of C++20 (which [g++10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html) is [supposed to fully support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)), not an added library.

Comment: Your `f` routine doesn't look like the one from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines  ... is that relevant?  (I'm not familiar with C++20 coroutines, yet.  I'm still in C++14 land.)

Comment: `f` needs to return a special type which fulfills the coroutine customization points. `int` is not such a type. https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro has some types which I've heard work for this sort of thing. This particular use sounds like a `generator<int>` or something of that sort.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. Alas, generator (which would be perfect!) is not part of the C++ standard. I have edited the question to clarify that I want c++20 as is rather than the libraries constructed before the standard was available.

Comment: @TopologicalSort Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562432/2069064) has already made clear that there is no `generator` in C++20. If you're not going to accept a different library, then I don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: @Barry: He's looking for you to write `generator` or something like it for him. Basically, he wants to understand how the coroutine machinery works.

Comment: Essentially I'm looking for a very simple program that uses `co_yield` (that is, what I tried to create above).

Comment: Eljay, I appreciate your looking into this. I did try all 3 snippets of code from the page you linked, but they don't compile. It's unclear whether they need an include, and as Barry notes one of them definitely isn't in the standard. I'd say that page is no longer accurate.

Comment: @TopologicalSort: There is no such thing as "a very simple program that uses `co_yield`". Or `co_await`. Because there is virtually no support for awaitable or generator types in the C++20 standard library, that means that to use them, you must either you must use a library that provides awaitable/generator types or *build* such types yourself.

Comment: Without referencing generator types (I just want something that compiles, whatever it may do)...I think you're saying that there can be no short or simple compilable program that has the keyword 'co_yield` in it. If so, I'll give up on it. Can that really be? A keyword that can't be simply demonstrated?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a minimal working example with gcc 10.1 of a coroutine `myCoroutineFunction` that uses just `co_yield` and does not have a `co_return`

It uses a counted for loop. A range for loop requires a little more work to write an iterator.

The return type of a coroutine is a generator object that needs a promise object to track the current value of the coroutine.

Because the generator and promise depend on each other, it's convenient to make the promise a nested class of the generator.

Every time the coroutine yields a value, the value is maintained by the promise while the coroutine is suspended

Client code interacts with the generator that provides methods to access the current coroutine value and to advance the coroutine after suspension

```cpp
// coroutine.cpp

// g++ -ocoroutine -g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Wextra
// -std=c++20 -fcoroutines -fno-exceptions coroutine.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <coroutine>

using namespace std;

struct Generator {
  struct Promise;

// compiler looks for promise_type
  using promise_type=Promise;
  coroutine_handle<Promise> coro;

  Generator(coroutine_handle<Promise> h): coro(h) {}

  ~Generator() {
    if(coro)
      coro.destroy();
  }

// get current value of coroutine
  int value() {
    return coro.promise().val;
  }

// advance coroutine past suspension
  bool next() {
    coro.resume();
    return !coro.done();
  }

  struct Promise {
// current value of suspended coroutine
    int val;

// called by compiler first thing to get coroutine result
    Generator get_return_object() {
      return Generator{coroutine_handle<Promise>::from_promise(*this)};
    }

// called by compiler first time co_yield occurs
    suspend_always initial_suspend() {
      return {};
    }

// required for co_yield
    suspend_always yield_value(int x) {
      val=x;
      return {};
    }

// called by compiler for coroutine without return
    suspend_never return_void() {
      return {};
    }

// called by compiler last thing to await final result
// coroutine cannot be resumed after this is called
    suspend_always final_suspend() {
      return {};
    }
  };

};

Generator myCoroutineFunction(int n) {

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    co_yield i;
  }

}
```

```cpp
int main ()
{
  int n=10;

  Generator myCoroutineResult = myCoroutineFunction(n);

  for(int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    myCoroutineResult.next();
    printf("%d ", myCoroutineResult.value());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run

```sh
$ g++ -ocoroutine -g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Wextra \
-std=c++20 -fcoroutines -fno-exceptions coroutine.cpp
$ ./coroutine
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Tested your example with g++-10.
According to it, your example cannot work unless...:
1) You add to your ```struct Promise``` an ```unhandle_exception```. Something like: ```void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }```.
2) In case you want to use the ```std::terminate()```, you have 2 options:
a) Or you add ```#include<exception>``` (if you want to preserve ```<stdio.h>``` (better ```cstdio```).
b) Or you do not add  ```<exception>```, but replace ```<stdio.h>``` with ```<iostream>``` (with the change in main for console output: ```cout``` instead of ```printf```).

Comment: Works like a charm with gcc 10.2. Thanks a million, this is quite a significant answer. Wish I could upvote a dozen times, saved me a ton of work.

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

> What should that top line of f look like, so I get a working coroutine?

---

I have modified your code as below. Please pay special attention to return type of f.

```
Couroutine_Example_Generator<int> f() { for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) co_yield i; }

int main ()
{
    for (auto i = f(); i.move_next(); )
    {
        std::cout << i.current_value() << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see complete Godbolt code for the changes that I did to your code. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/s6a9do).

> Or does something else need to be done to make a working coroutine?

---

Yes. C++20 specification requires promise_type to be provided.
So, I have defined a templatized version of generator in a header class which you can look [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atulmehra/moderncpp-code-examples/master/cpp20_code_examples/coroutines/include/templatized_generator.h). Or see a slightly different code example in my [repository](https://github.com/atulmehra/moderncpp-code-examples/tree/master/cpp20_code_examples/coroutines).

---

Additional relevant details in case you are interested.
Here are relevant excerpts from C++20 specification

> The promise type of a coroutine is std::coroutine_traits<R, P1, . . . , Pn>::promise_type.
> A coroutine behaves as if its function-body were replaced by:

---

```
{
  promise-type promise promise-constructor-arguments ;
  try {
  co_await promise .initial_suspend() ;
  function-body
```