# Can I use std::generator in a C++20 project to generate a range view?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++-coroutine, c++23

C++23 introduces the range view `std::generator` which is used as the return of a coroutine. With the previous views it is often difficult to generate a complex sequence of data. I think using a coroutine simplifies this a lot.

Unfortunately `std::generator` is currently not implemented by any standard library and in many projects C++20 will remain the standard for a while. Is there a way to use `std::generator` in a C++20 project?

Comment: "*With the previous views it is often difficult to generate a complex sequence of data. I think using a coroutine simplifies this a lot.*" Wit the rather substantial caveat that `generator`s are input ranges and thus cannot support multipass iteration.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, as the name suggests. I don't quite understand what you're getting at, could you please rephrase the criticism?

Comment: You talked about this as a replacement for generator views. Specifically, "With the previous views it is often difficult to generate a complex sequence of data.". Something like `iota | transform`. Well, that range is random-access, while the `generator` equivalent is an input range.

Comment: There is also an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562242/c20-in-g10-generator-not-defined, though it's not as complete as the answer below.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, okay. Yeah, that's a good point. I have added a paragraph in the answer addressing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the reference implementation of [`std::generator`](https://github.com/lewissbaker/generator).

The following C++23 program prints the first 10 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence.

```cpp
import std;

std::generator<int> fibonacci() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    co_yield a;
    while (true) {
        co_yield a = std::exchange(b, a + b);
    }
}

int main() {
    for (auto const& v: fibonacci() | std::views::take(10)) {
        std::print("{} ", v);
    }
    std::print("\n");
}
```

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

This program uses three C++23 elements that need to be replaced for C++20: [`std::generator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator), [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) and `import std` ([Standard Library Modules](https://wg21.link/P2465R3)).

The following C++20 variant uses the [reference implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewissbaker/generator/e7c6c1c/include/__generator.hpp) of `std::generator`, `iostream`s and header includes instead.

```cpp
#include "__generator.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <ranges>

std::generator<int> fibonacci() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    co_yield a;
    while (true) {
        co_yield a = std::exchange(b, a + b);
    }
}

int main() {
    for (auto const& v: fibonacci() | std::views::take(10)) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The `std::print` can alternatively be replaced by the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library (`std::print("{}\n", 5)` == `fmt::print("{}\n", 5)`).

## Build the examples with a C++20 compiler

If you save the examples of this post as `main.cpp`, the following `CMakeLists.txt` can be used to compile them with a C++20 compiler.

This is just a workaround to compile the examples of this post unchanged with a C++20 compiler. Such source code modifying customization is error prone and should not be used in production code!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

file(DOWNLOAD
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewissbaker/generator/e7c6c1c/include/__generator.hpp"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/generator.hpp")
file(DOWNLOAD
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fmtlib/fmt/9.1.0/include/fmt/core.h"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/core.h")
file(DOWNLOAD
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fmtlib/fmt/9.1.0/include/fmt/format.h"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/format.h")
file(DOWNLOAD
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fmtlib/fmt/9.1.0/include/fmt/format-inl.h"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/format-inl.h")
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/replace.cmake"
[=[
file(READ "${SOURCE}" TEXT)
string(CONCAT HEADERS [==[
#if __has_include(<print>)
#include <print>
#else
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "external/core.h"
namespace std { using fmt::print; }
#endif
#if __has_include(<generator>)
#include <generator>
#else
#include "external/generator.hpp"
#endif
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
#line 2 ]==] "\"${SOURCE}\"\n")
string(REGEX REPLACE "^ *import +std *; *\n" "${HEADERS}" TEXT "${TEXT}")
file(WRITE "${TARGET}" "${TEXT}")
]=])
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/out.cpp"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
        "-DSOURCE=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp"
        "-DTARGET=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/out.cpp"
        -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/replace.cmake"
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp")

project(main)
add_executable(main "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/out.cpp")
target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
```

The `DOWNLOAD` lines download the reference implementation of `std::generator` and parts of the `fmt` library for `fmt::print`.

Then a file `replace.cmake` is created. This is set up as a custom command. This will be executed whenever `main.cpp` has changed since the last build. It replaces `import std;` with the following code. This creates a new `out.cpp` in the build directory that contains C++20 code and includes the downloaded files if necessary.

```cpp
#if __has_include(<print>)
#include <print>
#else
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "external/core.h"
namespace std { using fmt::print; }
#endif
#if __has_include(<generator>)
#include <generator>
#else
#include "external/generator.hpp"
#endif
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <utility>
#include <string_view>
#line 2 /path/to/original/main.cpp
```

The first and second blocks bind either the C++23 header or the plugin replacement. If applicable `fmt::print` is made available as `std::print`. Note that you are not allowed to add anything to the namespace `std`! Since this is just a workaround and we also know that `std::print` does not exist in this case, we ignore this rule.

Then the normal headers which are necessary to translate the examples are included.

The last line tells the compiler that in the case of any error messages it should behave as if it were currently in the original `main.cpp` in line 2.

The `add_executable` must refer to the generated `out.cpp`.

## Usage of `std::generator`

As already seen in the Fibonacci example, an unlimitted sequence can be generated with `std::generator`. In the following example, we use a parameter to specify a starting value for the sequence. Then we use `std::views::take` again to limit the sequence.

```cpp
import std;

auto day_of_the_week(std::size_t start = 0)
-> std::generator<std::string_view> {
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 7> days =
        {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
    for (std::size_t i = start % days.size(); true; i = (i + 1) % days.size()) {
        co_yield days[i];
    }
}

auto main() -> int {
    for (std::string_view day: day_of_the_week(5) | std::views::take(3)) {
        std::print("Today is {}\n", day);
    }
}
```

```
Today is Sat
Today is Sun
Today is Mon
```

To directly define a limited range, we simply let the control flow of the coroutine run out.

```cpp
import std;

auto day_of_the_week(std::size_t start = 0, std::size_t count = 7)
-> std::generator<std::string_view> {
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 7> days =
        {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        co_yield days[(i + start) % days.size()];
    }
}

auto main() -> int {
    for (std::string_view day: day_of_the_week(3, 5)) {
        std::print("Today is {}\n", day);
    }
}
```

```
Today is Thu
Today is Fri
Today is Sat
Today is Sun
Today is Mon
```

Alternatively, this could also be done by an explicit `co_return;` statement.

```cpp
import std;

auto day_of_the_week(std::size_t start = 0, std::size_t count = 7)
-> std::generator<std::string_view> {
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 7> days =
        {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; true; ++i) {
        if(i >= count) {
            co_return;
        }
        co_yield days[(i + start) % days.size()];
    }
}

auto main() -> int {
    for (std::string_view day: day_of_the_week(3, 5)) {
        std::print("Today is {}\n", day);
    }
}
```

```
Today is Thu
Today is Fri
Today is Sat
Today is Sun
Today is Mon
```

## `std::generator` is an input range

A limitation of the `std::generator` approach is that it is a simple input range. With `iota | transform` on the other hand random access range can be generated.

```cpp
import std;

auto main() -> int {
    auto day_of_the_week =
        std::views::iota(std::size_t()) |
        std::views::transform([](std::size_t i){
            static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 7> days =
                {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
            return days[i % days.size()];
        });

    for(std::size_t i = 1000; i < 1003; ++i) {
        std::print("Day {} is {}\n", i, day_of_the_week[i]);
    }
}
```

```
Day 1000 is Sun
Day 1001 is Mon
Day 1002 is Tue
```

If you need random access, you cannot not use `std::generator`.

## Remarks on the examples

```cpp
auto function() -> ReturnType {}
```

is just another notation for

```cpp
ReturnType function() {}
```

I use this notation because for long lines the return data type can be wrapped to a separate line in a nice and clear way. It avoids side scrolling in the examples. This notation is not coroutine specific, it applies just as well to normal functions. Note that the return data type is even always specified this way for lambda functions.

```cpp
import std;
```

With `import std` the whole standard library can be included via modules starting from C++23. This `import` compiles faster than including a single standard library header via `#include`. You don't need to remember what was declared in which header anymore.

Comment: You cannot put definitions into the `std` namespace.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is not a real world problem. The definition is only inserted if the (almost) identical C++23 is not available. So it never leads to conflicts. Besides, this is anyway just a workaround to be able to compile the examples without changing the code. I didn't mean to suggest using something like this in production code! I have added appropriate warnings in the post, thanks for the input.